# Problem with Projection Matrix, a 1:1:1 cube looks stretched along the z axis

Tags: c#, matrix, opengl, game-engine, renderer

I am working on a renderer, and I am having some troubles with the perspective projection matrix.

Following is my perspective projection matrix.

```
public static Matrix4 Projection(float _zNear, float _zFar, float _Width, float _Height, float _fov)
{
        float _ar = _Width / _Height;
        float _tanHalffov = (float)Math.Tan(Math_of_Rotation.Radians_of(_fov / 2));
        float _zRange = _zFar - _zNear;

        return new Matrix4(new Vector4(1/(_tanHalffov * _ar), 0                 , 0                             , 0),
                           new Vector4(0                    , 1 / _tanHalffov   , 0                             , 0),
                           new Vector4(0                    , 0                 , -(_zFar + _zNear) / _zRange   , 2*_zNear*_zFar / _zRange),
                           new Vector4(0                    , 0                 , 1                             , 0));
}
```

I then multiplied it with the camera's transform matrix and the model's transform matrix.

it works but the z direction seems stretched a bit, and if I make zFar larger, the stretching is even more obvious, so I figured it may be something to do with the zRange, but I have divided it with zRange in the matrix, so isn't it supposed to be rescaled?

Following is the result of my program.
[the 1:1:1 cube looks weird after the projection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2HEe.png)
[even weirder in the corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeUIx.png)

---Update---

This is the vertex shader

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 texCoord;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 normal;

uniform vec3 cam_pos;
uniform mat4 transform;
uniform mat4 nptransform;

vec4 temp_Pos;

out vec3 normal0;
out vec2 texCoord0;
out vec3 cam_angle;
out vec3 position0;

void main()
{
    temp_Pos = nptransform * vec4(position, 1.0);
    position0 = vec3(temp_Pos.x,temp_Pos.y,temp_Pos.z);
    cam_angle = normalize(cam_pos - position0);
    normal0 = normal;
    texCoord0 = texCoord;
    gl_Position = transform * vec4(position, 1.0);//the bug is about this line
}
```

The following is the complete code of my matrix

```
public Matrix4 GetTransform(Vector3 _OffSet)
{
    return Matrix4.Translation(Position - _OffSet) * Matrix4.RotateX(Rotation.x) * Matrix4.RotateY(Rotation.y) * Matrix4.RotateZ(Rotation.z) * Matrix4.Scale(Scale.x, Scale.y, Scale.z);
}

public Matrix4 GetProjectdTransform(Vector3 _OffSet)//This is the one I sent to the shader.
{
        Transform CameraTransform = Core.The_Camera.Attaching_GameObject.transform;
        
        return Matrix4.Projection(Core.MainCamera.zNear, Core.MainCamera.zFar, Core.MainCamera.Width, Core.MainCamera.Height, Core.MainCamera.fov) * Matrix4.RotateX(CameraTransform.Rotation.x) * Matrix4.RotateY(CameraTransform.Rotation.y) * Matrix4.RotateZ(CameraTransform.Rotation.z) * Matrix4.CameraTranslation(CameraTransform.Position) * GetTransform(_OffSet);
}
```

And there is the detail of the matrix functions, but there shouldn't be any problem, I tested them a lot of times.

```
    public static Matrix4 CameraTranslation(Vector3 _CameraPosition)
    {
        return new Matrix4(new Vector4(1, 0, 0, -_CameraPosition.x),
                           new Vector4(0, 1, 0, -_CameraPosition.y),
                           new Vector4(0, 0, 1, -_CameraPosition.z),
                           new Vector4(0, 0, 0, 1));
    }

    public static Matrix4 Translation(Vector3 _Position)
    {
        return new Matrix4(new Vector4(1, 0, 0, _Position.x), 
                           new Vector4(0, 1, 0, _Position.y), 
                           new Vector4(0, 0, 1, _Position.z), 
                           new Vector4(0, 0, 0, 1));
    }

    public static Matrix4 Scale(float _x, float _y, float _z)
    {
        return new Matrix4(new Vector4(_x, 0, 0, 0),
                           new Vector4(0, _y, 0, 0),
                           new Vector4(0, 0, _z, 0),
                           new Vector4(0, 0, 0, 1));
    }

    public static Matrix4 RotateX(float _Angle)
    {
        double _Radians = Math_of_Rotation.Radians_of(_Angle);
        return new Matrix4(new Vector4(1, 0, 0, 0), 
                           new Vector4(0, (float)Math.Cos(_Radians), (float)Math.Sin(_Radians), 0), 
                           new Vector4(0, -(float)Math.Sin(_Radians), (float)Math.Cos(_Radians), 0), 
                           new Vector4(0, 0, 0, 1));
    }

    public static Matrix4 RotateY(float _Angle)
    {
        double _Radians = Math_of_Rotation.Radians_of(_Angle);
        return new Matrix4(new Vector4((float)Math.Cos(_Radians), 0, -(float)Math.Sin(_Radians), 0), 
                           new Vector4(0, 1, 0, 0),
                           new Vector4((float)Math.Sin(_Radians), 0, (float)Math.Cos(_Radians), 0), 
                           new Vector4(0, 0, 0, 1));
    }

    public static Matrix4 RotateZ(float _Angle)
    {
        double _Radians = Math_of_Rotation.Radians_of(_Angle);
        return new Matrix4(new Vector4((float)Math.Cos(_Radians), -(float)Math.Sin(_Radians), 0, 0), 
                           new Vector4((float)Math.Sin(_Radians), (float)Math.Cos(_Radians), 0, 0), 
                           new Vector4(0, 0, 1, 0), 
                           new Vector4(0, 0, 0, 1));
    }
    public static Matrix4 Projection(float _zNear, float _zFar, float _Width, float _Height, float _fov)
    {
        float _ar = _Width / _Height;
        float _tanHalffov = (float)Math.Tan(Math_of_Rotation.Radians_of(_fov / 2));
        float _zRange = _zFar - _zNear;
        
        return new Matrix4(new Vector4((_tanHalffov )       , 0                 , 0                             , 0),
                           new Vector4(0                    , _tanHalffov       , 0                             , 0),
                           new Vector4(0                    , 0                 , -(_zFar + _zNear) / _zRange   , 2*_zNear*_zFar / _zRange),
                           new Vector4(0                    , 0                 , 1                             , 0));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Rabbid76 Thanks very very much for your helps. I solved the question. The answer is...... I was never wrong. I ran through tons of test, and I found that the answer were in deed correct, and the outcome is suppose to look that wired. Cause, if you think about it the projection matrix makes x and y smaller while fov is larger(wider view means smaller object), but cause z is the input of a linear function

```
(_zFar + _zNear) / (_zFar - _zNear) * z + -2 * _zNear * _zFar / (_zFar - _zNear)
```

so when changing fov the length of a cube's z is never change but the x and y is smaller, that's why it looks weird.

As the hints @Rabbid76 so kindly to remind me, I think cause my game engine is also left handed system, so the matrix is different.

Proof: [Cube in unity also looks wired when the fov is 90](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LICa.png)

And:  [So as mine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeUIx.png)

Comment: In any case, your matrix is different from the usual OpenGL perspective matrix. And your coordinate system is right handed. If it were left handed you would get a mirroring effect along an axis. You have to swap m[2][3] and m[3][2] if you don't transpose the matrix when you set it to the uniform. As a matter of fact the normalized device space is a left handed system. Since your matrix doesn't invert an axis, your coordinate system is also left handed. This is not common.

Comment: I know you are right about my matrix, because other resources also say the same. I am not good at math, but I do knew my coordinate system is left handed, I intended it, I imitated Unity(which is also left handed) when I was designing my game engine. Anyway, having bug or not, I do learn a lot. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to transpose the matrix and invert some components if you want to do the same as `Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView`.

```cs
public static Matrix4 Projection(float _zNear, float _zFar, float _Width, float _Height, float _fov)
{
    float _ar = _Width / _Height;
    float _tanHalffov = (float)Math.Tan(Math_of_Rotation.Radians_of(_fov / 2));
    float _zRange = _zFar - _zNear;

    return new Matrix4(new Vector4(1/(_tanHalffov * _ar), 0              , 0                          ,  0),
                       new Vector4(0                    , 1 / _tanHalffov, 0                          ,  0),
                       new Vector4(0                    , 0              , -(_zFar + _zNear) / _zRange, -1),
                       new Vector4(0                    , 0              , -2*_zNear*_zFar / _zRange  ,  0));
}
```

OpenGL matrices are stored in column-major order. The 1st column is the x-axis, followed by the y- and z-axes. The fourth column is the translation.
This means that each line (`Vector4`) represents one column of the matrix.

The usual OpenGL coordinate system is a right handed system. In view space the z-axis points against the line of sight. The Normalized Device Space is a left handed system. Therefore the z-axis is inverted by the projection matrix. See [Left- vs. Right-handed coordinate systems](https://www.evl.uic.edu/ralph/508S98/coordinates.html).

You can find a working C#/OpenTK example at [3D Geometry](https://github.com/Rabbid76/c_sharp_opengl#3d-geometry)

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you meant, but I tried changing the row to column before I sent it to the shader, but it became weirder. So I am going though each matrices and check the outcomes of each step. Just to make sure, the outcome of (perspective projection matrix * world space vector) should be in the range of -1~1 in all three axis, right?

Comment: @Vinny No it is not. When you transform the vertex with the projection matrix (or MVP-matrix), you get a clipspace coordinate (this is a [Homogeneous coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates)). If you want a normalized device coordinate (NDS is a unique cube +/- 1) you have to do a [Perspective divide](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing#Perspective_divide). I don't know what is wrong in your code (the one I can't see). However, I do not guess here. I know that my suggestions are correct.

Comment: By the way, thanks for your codes, but I am not using OpenTK, but GLFW's wrapper for C#, so I don't have all the good stuffs such as  Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView. Still, thanks very much.

Comment: Sure, I think I'd better do some studies before continue. I know it's a pain in the ass trying to debug for someone when not able to see the code. So thanks very much for answering my question.

Comment: @Vinny Some resources: [OpenGL Projection Matrix](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html), [The Perspective and Orthographic Projection Matrix](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/perspective-and-orthographic-projection-matrix/opengl-perspective-projection-matrix), [Coordinate Systems](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Coordinate-Systems), [Camera](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Camera).

Comment: I have updated the code, if you want to see it. Of course, feel free not to if it's troublesome.

Comment: Ok, so I kind of starting to understand what the Perspective projection Matrix is doing, I have a vertex point (1,1,1) on my cube object, and after the translation, the point became world position(1,1,1,1), which is right, since my cube is at world position(0,0,0), with scale(1,1,1) and Euler rotation(0,0,0), and then after the camera translation the point became world point related to the camera, which is position(1,1,21,0), cause my camera is at world position(0,0,-20), so far so good

Comment: and the bug happen in the next step, the projection matrix, after the projection matrix, the point became(0.5, 1, 20.524576, 21), I can understand x and y, cause my window ratio is 1200:600, so the x is half the size(that's why _ar is in the matrix for). but I still can not figure out z.

Comment: OK, so now I understand the z,the z will be relocated from world position to clip space where the zNear is 0 and zFar is still zFar, and then, the xyz will be divided by w(which is the z of the space where camera is the center), then the xyz will finally be in the space where all three axis are in the range of -1~1

Comment: But if that's the case ,then how would my code work(sort of), since I had never divide the xyz by w? I found some information that the glsl shader can accept clipspace points, so does it mean that glsl is doing it for me?